# Trouble deleting from model using Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, sql-delete

Im new to backbone and trying to figure out how to make a button that deletes all data of a table in the db. I've looked around all day trying to find solutions to achieve this and have come up empty. I tried using `this.listenTo(this.model, 'destroy'. this.remove);` but when that line is uncommented I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: this.listenTo is not a function`. I am using rails 3.0.7 with backbone. Any ideas?

```
window.UserView = Backbone.View.extend({
 tagName: "tr",

 events: { 
  "click": "clear"
 },

 initialize: function() {   
    // this.listenTo(this.model, 'destroy', this.remove);   
 },

 render: function(){
  var user = this.model.toJSON();
  $(this.el).html(ich.dart_template(user));
  return this;
 },

 clear: function() {
  this.$el.remove();
  this.model.destroy();
 }
});
```

Comment: Which version of Backbone are you using? `listenTo` was added in 0.9.9 circa December 2012.

Comment: Backbone.js 0.3.3 that would explain it @muistooshort

Comment: Wow, time runs so quickly, we have `listenTo` in Backbone for almost three years now. Definitely update your Backbone, Jacob, and the code will work.

Comment: @Yura There's an ancient Backbone tutorial near the top of Google's search results that references 0.3.3, this particular problem comes up a fair bit.